# Azure Portal login issue due incorrect WS-Federation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureportal

I have recently trying to implement SSO solution with Azure AD. I have made mistake of federating all user of the azure ad domain, which is causing the login to occur with federated IDP service for portal.

I think I have also mis-configured SAML attributes as well because of which I get IDP login screen instead of Microsoft login and I cant login to portal due to SAML mis-configuration.

So I am stuck here without login to azure portal console. How do I de-federate Azure AD with console access.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Refer this doc to [remove federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation#how-do-i-remove-federation)

Answer (score 0):

***Steps to implement SSO solution with AAD***

- Deploy your Application to Azure portal App Service
- Navigate to the AAD => Enterprise Applications => new Application = > Select Non-Gallery Option

[image]

- To **Configure single sign-on (SSO)**
  Navigate to the Enterprise application which you have created => Single sign-on
  [image]

[image]
To get the identifier
Navigate to AAD => Enterprise application => New Application => I sarch box search with Proxyclick, select  and create

[image]

- From Single-sign on => Download the base64 certificate
  [image]

***To remove WS-Federation***

AAD => External Identities =>All Identity Providers => Under SAML /WS-Federation Identity Providers => Select link in Domain and Delete Configuration => Confirm

[image]

References taken from [SSO](https://proxyclick.help/en/articles/4214835-how-to-implement-sso-and-user-provisioning-through-azure-active-directory)